# Number of JMS listeners on MQ

Tags: java, jms, mq, listeners

We are developing an application in JAVA. We will use JMS to listen to messages coming on to MQ. We are expecting around 100K message from approx 100 users (each message approx. 1400 charachters long) per day. How many listeners is good to have for this scenario. What I am trying to know is, how many messages a JMS listeners can process per unit. Approximate number is enough for now. Is there a documentation where we can find out this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at two things here: server performance and client performance.
Major JMS providers (HornetQ, ActiveMQ, etc.) can easily handle 5000+ messages per second, so you are covered on that side (if you want more information have a look at the [SPECjms2007 results](http://www.spec.org/jms2007/results/)).

Client performance depends on the computing power of your clients (obviously) and what you want to do with those messages. Technically, there isn't a limit in how many messages a client can process. My experience is that message marshalling/unmarshalling is a huge factor, so as a rough estimate you can assume that your client can handle about the same message load as your server, assuming equally powerful machines and light processing of message content.

In the end you will want to do some load testing.

Comment: Thank you. This helps for now. Let me evaluate the answer before i come up with some more questions. :).